# Create a byte array from a file?

Tags: arrays, abap

My ABAP devs are sending me file through a function. I'm trying to find out if I can convert a file into a byte array in ABAP>.

If this is possible, does anyone have any example code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
data: w_line type xstring.
data: t_file type table of xstring.
data: w_filename type string falue 'myfile.txt'.
data: w_len type i.

open dataset w_filename for input in binary mode.

read dataset w_filename into w_line length w_len.

while w_len > 0.
    append w_line to t_file.
    read dataset w_filename into w_line length w_len.
endwhile.

close dataset w_filename.

* t_file now holds the data in an internal table
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a handful of ways to do it, but I've found using Objects is easiest.

```
DATA byte_array TYPE TABLE OF raw256. "any type will work here
DATA my_file    TYPE string VALUE `C:\users\bob\file.bin`. "Absolute or relative works

CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_UPLOAD(
  EXPORTING
    filename = my_file
    filetype = 'BIN'
  CHANGING
    data_tab = byte_array ).
```

This class is very robust from my experience.  There are a bunch of optional parameters and return codes.  SAP wrote some great documentation [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/en/1d/ac0155370648569fe843170e07c4da/content.htm?frameset=/en/dd/66b1a76d7044ff8fd46c04fdaec220/frameset.htm).